# Difference in variable value inside and outside a function

Tags: c, function, return-value, output, structured-programming

I wrote a program in which I found the area of cylinder using a function`area` with a return-type and without parameters. `answer`was returned to `main` function. However, I am getting different output in `main` and a different output in `area`. The decimal places seem to be replaced by 0 in the `main` function. Why is it so?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the return type of area from int to float

Answer (score 1):

Your function returns an `int` which truncates any real part of the value.

```
float area()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `answer` is float in area function but return type of area function is `int`. so it typed cased during return, in main

```
int area(){
 ^  should be float

 float answer;

 // print float
 return answer;
}

int main(){
 answer = area(); // answer gets integral part
 // print int part
}
```